# What is the use of the particle "は" in this sentence?

Tags: translation, particle-は, song-lyrics, grammar

I'm currently translating the lyrics of "Realize" by Konomi Suzuki. And the one thing that made me confused was the use of the particle "は" in this sentence of the lyrics.
歩き続けた今を消しては 見ない様に塞いだ過去
Is the "は" working as a topic marker particle making the sentence after the particle the predicate or is it indicating contrast between the two sentences? I need some help.